# python regex for incomplete decimals numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have a string of numbers which may have incomplete decimal reprisentation

for example

```
a = '1. 1,00,000.00  1 .99 1,000,000.999'
```

desired output

```
['1','1,00,000.00','1','.99','1,000,000.999']
```

so far i have tried the following 2

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)',a)
```

which gives

```
['1', '1,00,000.00', '1', '99', '1,000,000.999']
```

which makes .99 to 99 which is not desired

while

```
re.findall(r'[-+]?(\d*(?:[.,]\d+)*)',a)
```

gives

```
['1', '', '', '1,00,000.00', '', '', '1', '', '.99', '', '1,000,000.999', '']
```

which gives undesirable empty string results as well

this is for finding currency values in a string so the commas separators don't have a set pattern or mat not be present at all

Comment: `[-+]?(\.?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*)`?

Comment: Also why don't you want the `.` after `1`?

Comment: the . after 1 is redundant. I am okay if it shows up or doesn't show up

Comment: chrisz comment is best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the regex below:

I've implemented a snippet in python.

```
import re

a = '1. 1,00,000.00  1 .99 1,000,000.999'

result = re.split('/\.?\d\.?\,?/', a)

print result
```

Output:

['1', '1,00,000.00', '1', '.99', '1,000,000.999']

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
a = '1. 1,00,000.00  1 .99 1,000,000.999'
d = re.split('(?<=\d)\.\s+|(?<=\d)\s+', a)
```

Output:

```
['1', '1,00,000.00', '1', '.99', '1,000,000.999']
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will give you your desired output:

```
([0-9]+(?=\.))|([0-9,]+\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+)|(\.[0-9]+)
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/VfQIJC/6